# Need help on getting the following code to print in a new line per for loop and must end up as a return statement not print

Tags: python

```
def display(deposits, top, bottom, left, right):

    res = ''

    for row in range(top, bottom):
        for col in range(left, right):
            flag = 0
            for (index, tuples) in enumerate(deposits):
                if (tuples[0] == row and tuples[1] == col):
                    flag = 1
                    res += "X"
                    break
            if(flag == 0):
                res += "-"
    return res
```

Currently results in the following when I do `print(display(deposits, 0, 8, 0, 8))`

```
----X------------------------X-X-------------X----X------------X
```

How do I get `print(display(deposits, 0, 8, 0, 8))` to print in the following way below:

```
----X---

--------

--------

-----X-X

--------

-----X--

--X-----

-------X
```

Answer (score 1):

The str.join() method is the method of choice for adding strings inbetween a list of other strings. Try something like:

```
def display(deposits, top, bottom, left, right):
    rows = []
    for row in range(top, bottom):
        res = ''
        for col in range(left, right):
            flag = 0
            for (index, tuples) in enumerate(deposits):
                if (tuples[0] == row and tuples[1] == col):
                    flag = 1
                    res += "X"
                    break
            if(flag == 0):
                res += "-"
        rows.append(res)
    return '\n\n'.join(rows)
```